# Publishing SQL LocalDB to IIS Server "Server was not found..." Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, visual-studio-2015

so I've got a project that uses a localDB and I want to publish it to an IIS server. If I try to run it it gives me the error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
```

I've done some research and found this article: [Deployment of SQL Express LocalDB on IIS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gaurav/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis/#comments)

The article describes the exact problem I'm having but doesn't give a clear answer to solve it(as far as my understanding goes)

The tag below proved to be no use as I tried to put it in the ApplicationInsights.config and Web.Config file with no luck.(The article didn't specify where to put it exactly)

`<add name="DefaultAppPool">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
 </add>`

Does anyone have any information or input? Much appreciated.

Comment: is this on a web hosting site or do you have controll over the server?

Comment: @Thorarins It's on a school server hosted by my professor. I do not have any control over the server.

Answer (score 0):

You should have SQL Server Express service running on your IIS server. If it's not installed you should install it.

And, if you've assigned any particular account for your application pool identity make sure that user has Read/Write permissions to App_Data folder. this is where your local database file is created automatically during the first run.

Comment: Is there any tags that I can use in the web.config folder that will allow a user to read/write permissions to App_Data? If I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: No you cannot do that. you need to configure this in IIS.

Comment: You can use ASP.Net Configuration tool to control access to your folder. but, this intern uses a local DB and it is being created in the App_Data folder. And, when you publish this local DB file to IIS it'll not work due to server permissions. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNRC5HhJH5w